# Pegar elemento aleatório de uma List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, lista, random

Tenho uma `List<int> numeros`

É possível retornar um elemento aleatório dessa lista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Para uma ter isso em `.NET` faça:*

```
IList<int> listaNumeros = new List<int>() { 95, 4, 9, 52, 40, 800, 90, 11, 2, 9, 4, 92, 8, 91, 120, 111 };
Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
int resultado = listaNumeros[rand.Next(listaNumeros.Count)]
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/ITI5GS)

***Referências:***

- [Construtor Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Construtor Random (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Macoratti.net - C# - Gerando números aleatórios](http://www.macoratti.net/12/05/c_rand1.htm)

Comment: E' preferivel chamar o construtor de `Random` sem argumentos. O constructor sem argumentos usa `Environment.TickCount` (2^31 valores possiveis) como seed, que tem uma entropia muito maior do que `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` (1000 valores possiveis).

Comment: E' melhor usar o comportamento default. Alem disso, a grandeza do numero e' irrelevante - nao existe degradacao de performance. Muito pelo contrario, existe uma (ligeira) degradacao de performance em usar `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` pois implica fazer parse da data do sistema, interpretar a zona horario, e interpretar os milisegundos da hora actual. `Environment.TickCount` e' uma chamada directa ao kernel e  e', portanto, mais eficiente e garante um resultado mais aleatorio.

Answer (score 10):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma em `.net`:

```
var lista = new List<int>{3,5,1,8,4,9};
var rnd = new Random();
var valorAleatorio = lista[rnd.Next(lista.Count)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Um acrescento às demais respostas, na forma de um `extension method`:

```
private static Random _randGen = new Random();
public static T GetRandomElement<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    return source[_randGen.Next(0, source.Count)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(5);
    numeros.add(6);
    numeros.add(7);

    Random gerador = new Random();
    int index = gerador.nextInt(numeros.size());

    System.out.println(numeros.get(index));
```

Comment: C#. Botei na tag, porém esqueci de por no escopo da pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: Puts! Só agora percebi as tags c# e .net. Mas mesmo sendo em java ele pode usar a mesma lógica.